# Build multipart/form-data POST request in Angular2 and validate Input type File

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, post, angular2-forms

I have an image (base64) that I need to send via a POST request (and wait for the response).  The POST request needs to be of `Content-Type:multipart/form-data`.
The image needs to be of `Content-Type: image/jpg`

The POST request should look like:

```
POST https://www.url... HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=-------------------------acebdf13572468
User-Agent: Fiddler
Host: www.host.com
Content-Length: 199640

---------------------------acebdf13572468
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fieldNameHere"; filename="Nikon Digital SLR Camera D3100 14.2MP 2.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
```

With the binary image data as the content body.

I'm attempting to use the Http Post method of angular 2, but I'm not quite sure about how to generate the request.
This is what I have:

```
let body = atob(imageData);
let headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'});
let options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});

this._http.post(url, body, options)
.map(res=>{
  //do stuff
});
```

I can tell that I am missing part of it but I am not sure what I need to do to give the binary image data it's Content-Disposition & Type etc.

Answer (score 4):

**`Form template`**

```
<form id="form" name="file" [formGroup]="FileFormGroup"(submit)="addFrom($event, FileFormGroup)" method="post">  

   <input spellcheck="true" formControlName="Demo" name="Demo" type="text"/>
   <input type="file" accept="image/*" id="file" name="File"/>
   <input formControlName="File" type="hidden"/>

</form>
```

**`Ts`**

```
   import {FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators} from '@angular/forms';

   import {ValidatorFn} from '@angular/forms/src/directives/validators';

   public FileFormGroup: FormGroup; /* variable */

   constructor(public fb: FormBuilder) {}

   ngOnInit() {
      this.FileFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      Demo: ["", Validators.required],
      File: ["", this.fileExtension({msg: 'Please upload valid Image'})]
     });
   }

   public addFrom(event: Event, form: FormGroup): void {

   if(form.valid && form.dirty) {

   let formTemp: HTMLFormElement <HTMLFormElement>document.querySelector('#form');

   let formData: FormData = new FormData(formTemp);

   let xhr: XMLHttpRequest = this.foo(formData);

    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
        if(xhr.status === 201) {
           console.log("Success");
        } else {
           console.log("Error");
        }
      }
    }
  }}

    // Foo function
     public Foo(formData){
         let url: Foo;
         let xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
         xhr.open('POST', url, true);

         // enctype For Multipart Request
          xhr.setRequestHeader("enctype", "multipart/form-data");

          // IE bug fixes to clear cache
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control", "no-store");
          xhr.setRequestHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); 

          xhr.send(formData);
          return xhr;
     }

     /* validation function to check proper file extension */

  public fileExtension(config: any): ValidatorFn {
    return (control: FormControl) => {

      let urlRegEx: RegExp = /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i;

      if(control.value && !control.value.match(urlRegEx)) {
        this.deleteImg = false;
        return {
          invalidUrl: config.msg
        };
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    };
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to this question here: [Angular 2 - Post File to Web API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35142841/angular-2-post-file-to-web-api)

Angular2 does not yet support multipart/form-data POST requests, so I decided to use jQuery instead to implement it, and then convert it to an RxJs Observable (subject) to have the same type as what the http.post function in Angular2 should have:

```
//Convert Base64 Representation of jpeg to 
let imageData = imageString.split(',')[1];
let dataType = imageString.split('.')[0].split(';')[0].split(':')[1];
let binaryImageData = atob(imageData);
let data = new FormData();
let blob = new Blob([binaryImageData], { type: dataType })
data.append('file', blob);
let deferred = $.ajax({
  url: this._imageAPIBaseUrl,
  data: data,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  type: 'POST'
});
let observable = new AsyncSubject();

//When the Deferred is complete, push an item through the Observable
deferred.done(function () {

  //Get the arguments as an array
  let args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  //Call the observable next with the same parameters
  observable.next.apply(observable, args);

  //Complete the Observable to indicate that there are no more items.
  observable.complete();
});

//If the Deferred errors, push an error through the Observable
deferred.fail(function () {

  //Get the arguments as an array
  let args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  //Call the observable error with the args array
  observable.error.apply(observable, args);
  observable.complete();
});

return observable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this working example (not mine): https://plnkr.co/edit/ViTp47ecIN9kiBw23VfL?p=preview

1 - Don't change or set the Content-Type

2 - Use FormData to send parameters

3 - Add this to app.module.ts:

```
import { HttpModule, RequestOptions, XHRBackend, ConnectionBackend, Http, Request, RequestOptionsArgs, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
@Injectable()
export class HttpInterceptor extends Http {
    constructor(backend: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions: RequestOptions) 
    {
        super(backend, defaultOptions);
        defaultOptions.headers = new Headers();
        defaultOptions.headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    }
}
```